# How to solve installation error when installing scikit-extreme?

Tags: python-3.7

I tried to install scikit-extremes but I am getting this error:

```
pip install scikit-extremes
Collecting scikit-extremes
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scikit-extremes (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for scikit-extremes
```

Please help me in installing scikit-extreme by providing the proper step-by-step procedure.

Comment: Actually sir i also tried that commands also but it was showing for some requirements and as mentioned their in dependencies i have all numpy matplotlib NumDifftools scipy......... But still it showing after giving command that 1 requirement is their actually sir I don't have lmomemts3 installed....

Comment: Please use the **[edit]** link to update your question. _All_ the relevant information should be _clearly_ described in your question, including all the attempts you've made and all the errors/issues you are having. It helps potential helpers to reproduce your problem and to avoid repeating what you've already tried. It also minimizes discussions of the problem through comments. See [ask].

Comment: I don't know what error you're getting. I did exactly the same steps as in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56473756/2745495) and it installed successfully. What is your OS and python version?

Comment: Windows 10 and python 3.7.3

Answer (score 1):

The package does not seem to be available yet on pypi (you can [search for it](https://pypi.org/search/?q=scikit-extremes)), and it's also explained by the package author in https://github.com/kikocorreoso/scikit-extremes/issues/2:

> Upload package to pypi.
>
> Why it is not on pypi yet?
>
> - This package is work in progress. There isn't a release so no package
>     has been uploaded to pypi.

The alternate installation steps are described instead here:
https://github.com/kikocorreoso/scikit-extremes#installation

> **Installation**
>
> To install the package you can follow the next steps:
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/kikocorreoso/scikit-extremes.git
>
> cd scikit-extremes
>
> pip install -e .
> ```